# What is the OpenMP runtime needed for?

Tags: openmp

I'm running Arch Linux. I ran a couple of OpenMP programs on this machine, both C and Fortran, never noticing anything strange or unexpected. The correct number of threads were always used.

Now I noticed that there is a package `openmp` available, which is not installed:

```
extra/openmp 3.9.1-1
    LLVM OpenMP Runtime Library
```

What is the OpenMP Runtime needed for if OpenMP works without it?

Comment: That's probably the OpenMP runtime used by Clang not by GCC.  GCC, ICC, and Clang each use there own OpenMP runtime. Though I think Clang's is based on Intel's. Intel's OpenMP runtimes is actually open source so I think that's what Clang's is based on but I don't know for sure. I use GCC and ICC but not Clang.

Comment: @Zboson, the Clang OpenMP runtime is the open-source Intel OpenMP runtime. Or the other way round...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runtime library is meant for the LLVM compiler, I know that in Black Arch (a penetration testing version of the Arch Linux) have gcc installed by default so your programs must be using it instead of LLVM (or clang).And default gcc installations also install OpenMP.